# how to get an editText string value in a childview in expandbleView?

Tags: java, android

I am not able to get the string value from editText"Amount" in childView of ExpandableListView. I used shared preference.

Here is my code

```
        case CHILD_TYPE_1:
            TextView description_child = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chidtext);
            description_child.setText(incoming_text);

            EditText editamoount=convertView.findViewById(R.id.editamount);
            editamoount.setBackground(null);
            break;
```

I am enclosing the screenshot of GUI.

ExpandableListView:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
String s=editamoont.gettext().tostring();
 int t= Integer.parseint(s);
```

second line is to convert your string to Int, just in case you need to.
hope it helps.

Comment: And also i want to pass that value to some other activity

Comment: i've tried running your snippet. convertView is not working for me. I type-casted it instead. and for passing your variables along activities you can use an Intent.

Comment: let me know if you want any snippets for it.. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your response,Please post your snippets

Answer (score 0):

extract the string:

```
        EditText editamoount= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editamount);
        String s=editamoont.gettext().tostring();
```

and then pass it to another activity:

```
    *in First one:
         Intent in = new Intent(FirstAct.this, SecondAct.class);
         in.putExtra("Tag",s);
         startActivity(in);

     *in Second one:
         Intent in1 = getIntent();
         String s1 = in1.getStringExtra("Tag");
```

that's all.